# How to get power spectrum (frequency vs intensity) for a sound signal in .wav format

Tags: r, audio, wav

I have lots of audio recordings in wave format and need to obtain power spectrum (frequency vs intensity) for different time frames in seconds.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do it with R? There are tools specifically designed for this purpose.

Comment: Do these help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13827980/how-to-convert-a-wave-file-into-numbers-in-r-studio  https://stackoverflow.com/q/13827980/6851825

Comment: @EugeneSh. could you tell me about such tools, I want to be able to obtain power spectrums dato to make multiple operations. Thank you